# How to mock function in same UUT in C

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded, cmock, unity-test-framework

I am learning unit testing using Ceedling, with CMock for mocks, on an existing, embedded C code-base (which I can adjust to suit).

I have come across the situation where one function in a unit calls a second function within the same unit.

```
int foo_a(int r) 
{
    /* foo_a work */
    /* do not wish to test this function just to test foo_b. */
}

int foo_b(int i) /* function to test */
{
    /* foo_b work */
    if (some_condition)
        foo_a(k); /* need to test if foo_a() is called or not. */
}
```

I don't want to test the `foo_a()` as part of the `foo_b()`  tests. How do I mock `foo_a()` so that I can still test if it is called or not but without testing the `foo_a()` function itself?

Comment: I don't know much about C, but if it's anything like many other languages, methods can be marked virtual/overridable.  In situations like this, you could then provide a mock/fake with a known/set return of `foo_a`.  This way, when utilizing the mock/fake class, when you.call `foo_b` you'll hit your mocked/overridden method of `foo_a` rather than the real impl so you can concentrate on testing `foo_b` without worrying about `foo_a` impl.

Comment: @kritner C  is not object orientated. It does not  have concepts such as virtual, overridable, inheritance or polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without modifying your source code.

Consider breaking the functions out into two separate compilation units.

Or, add an `#ifndef TEST` around the function you want to replace.

Comment: This allows me to introduce a fake, but how can I determine if the fake was called or not? First thoughts would be simply introducing a global flag that gets set if the fake is called and then checking for the flag in my test. Is there a better method or more recommended practice for such?

Answer (score 0):

On my experience using ceedling, the best way is to create a custom `TEST_ASSERT_FOO_A_IS_CALLED();` or , subtle difference, `TEST_ASSERT_IS_DOING_WHAT_FOO_A_SHOULD_BE_DOING();`
In the second case, you are testing if some set of action is being executed, not an internal function that you should not be aware of.

In theory, using unit tests you do not care how that function operates (I.E. you do not care if `foo_b()` calls `foo_a()`, as long `foo_b()` does the same things to mocked function as `foo_a()` ) and you SHOULD not be able to tell if an internal(private) function such as `foo_a()` is called. Therefore, you should be testing if the mocked functions are being called, not the internal function per se.

How to create a custom ASSERT?
it is simple, just define it using normal C macros, example:

```
#define TEST_ASSERT_FOO_A_IS_CALLED() \
{                                     \
  TEST_ASSERT_CALLED(some_mocked_function_foo_a_is_expected_to_call);                              \
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE(expected_value, some_mocked_function_foo_a_is_expected_to_call_fake.arg0_val, "Something wrong with arg0!"); \
}
```

Including the "_MESSAGE" asserts is not necessary but it is easier to spot which of the asserts inside the macro failed, since every 'fail' inside the macro will show the same line number, making more difficult to spot it.

If for some reason it is happening a lot, this is a signed that `foo_a()` should be in another source file that can be mocked.